# Calculate amount of times a interaction has been made by the same client id when a conversion is made

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a dataset like so :

| client_id | interaction_1 | interaction_2 | conversion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| C | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| A | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| B | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| C | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| C | 0 | 0 | 1 |

The dataset is already ordered based on a timestamp (ascending). Both the interactions and conversion columns are dummies (0/1). For every conversion, I need to calculate the amount a client_id did a interaction or conversion, but **only** the interactions since the last conversion (therefore, the column "lag_conversion" can never be >1).

The output should look something like this:

| client_id | interaction_1 | interaction_2 | conversion | lag_interaction_1 | lag_interaction_2 | lag_conversion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| C | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| A | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| C | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| C | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

I've tried the code:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(mydata)) {
  client_id <- mydata$client_id[i]
  if (mydata$conversion[i] == 1) {
    last_conversion_index <- max(which(mydata$client_id == client_id & mydata$conversion== 1 & 1:nrow(mydata) <= i))
    mydata$interaction_1[i:last_conversion_index & mydata$interaction_1== 1] <- 1
  }
}
```

although this only results in a 1 in the row itself, meaning that the first row would look like:

| client_id | interaction_1 | interaction_2 | conversion | lag_interaction_1 | lag_interaction_2 | lag_conversion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr) #1.1.0 and above
dat %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ ifelse(conversion == 1, cumsum(lag(.x, default = 0)), 0),
                .names = "lag_{col}"), .by = client_id)

  client_id interaction_1 interaction_2 conversion lag_interaction_1 lag_interaction_2 lag_conversion
1         A             1             0          0                 0                 0              0
2         B             0             1          0                 0                 0              0
3         C             0             0          1                 0                 0              0
4         A             0             0          1                 1                 0              0
5         B             0             1          0                 0                 0              0
6         B             0             0          1                 0                 2              0
7         C             0             1          0                 0                 0              0
8         C             0             0          1                 0                 1              1
```

below 1.1.0:

```r
dat %>% 
  group_by(client_id) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ ifelse(conversion == 1, cumsum(lag(.x, default = 0)), 0),
                .names = "lag_{col}")) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! However, this results in the following error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = across(...)`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Problem while computing column `lag_client_id`.
Caused by error in `lag()`:
! Can't combine `default` <double> and `x` <character>.
```

Comment: Convert your columns to numeric first

Comment: Note also that if you have dplyr below 1.1.0, you should use group by instead of .by

Comment: Ah I see, that worked, Thanks. I'm not fully familiar with the "everything" command. It seems to also create a lag for "client_id". Expanding the command to "everything(dat[,-c(1)])" doesn't seem to work as well, while temporarily removing client_id leaves us without a way to compare rows with each other. Any clues?

Comment: Check [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select.html) to understand how it works. `everything()` selects all columns

Comment: Ah i got it working, but it doesn't seem to take client_id into account. It just cumulatively sums the conversions of the whole dataset. It also calculates only the conversions, not the interactions

Comment: Yes, you are not grouping. Check your dplyr version and my comments above "Note also that if you have dplyr below 1.1.0, you should use group by instead of .by"

Comment: That doesnt seem to work as well, as it does not accept "client_id" as factor, numeric nor character. The code as it is now: 
mydata_new <- mydata_test %>% 
  mutate(across(-client_id, ~ ifelse(conversion == 1, cumsum(lag(.x, default = 0)), 0),
                .names = "lag_{col}"), group_by(client_id)).

Meanwhile, thanks for all your effort up until now!

Comment: chec kedit for version below 1.1.0 you're not use ungroup correctly